# Как вызывать по одной форме внутри Panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Проблема в том, что вызывая Form2 она открывается несколько раз до бесконечности. Может есть способ открывать только один раз, и при переходе на другую форму закрывать предыдущую?

Уточню, если несколько раз нажать на PictureBox1 или PictureBox2, формы будут созданы столько раз, сколько раз было нажато.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    private Form f1;
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f1 = new Form2();
        f1.TopLevel = false;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(f1);
        f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        f1.Show();
    }

    private Form f2;
    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2 = new Form3();
        f2.TopLevel = false;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(f2);
        f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        f2.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.panel1.Controls.Clear();

  if (f1 == null)
  {
    f1 = new Form2();
    f1.TopLevel = false;
    f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  }

  this.panel1.Controls.Add(f1);
  f1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, только в моем случае `if (f1 == null)`

Comment: @Vitokhv Пардон, конечно.